# Android make PDF

Tags: java, android, pdf, text, fonts

I have an Android application that gets user input from an interface with various views. I use these inputs as strings and print them on a PDF with the help of draw methods of canvas object, according to the premade template that I prepared. These work fine but I encountered some problem. Some letters in string have either too much space between other letters or very small space, which causes collision between letters. It makes terrible visuality in PDF file. I used "setletterspacing" method of paint object to set space length between letters but it did not work. How can I make all letters have same spacing while overall text looks fine?

```
 private void makePDF(){
    PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
    Paint paint=new Paint();

    PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(250,400,1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page myPage=document.startPage(myPageInfo);

    Canvas canvas=myPage.getCanvas();
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();

    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(10);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("İSG RİSK TESPİT VE DÖF FORMU",myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2,8,paint);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.NORMAL));

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    canvas.drawRect(1,20,(myPageInfo.getPageWidth())-1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-50,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/5,20,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/5,44,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10,20,7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10,44,paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);



    String[] blockKısım={"Tespit Tarihi","Uygunsuz lukYeri","Etkilenen Kişi/Grup","Alınmış Önlem"};
    String[] blockCevap={btnCallendar.getText().toString(),edUygunsuz.getText().toString(),edEtkilenen.getText().toString(),edAlinmisOnlem.getText().toString()};
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setTextSize(3f);
    //paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL));

    int startX=2;
    int startY=22;
    int endX=7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){

       // paint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.gray, null));

        canvas.drawText(blockKısım[i],startX,startY+3,paint);
        //paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL));
        canvas.drawText(blockCevap[i],(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/5)+2,startY+3,paint);
        //paint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.black, null));
        canvas.drawLine(startX,startY+4,endX,startY+4,paint);
        startY+=5;
    }

    canvas.drawText("Risk Derecesi",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-(2*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10)),25,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10,26,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,26,paint);


    String[] strRısk={"Olasılık","Frekans","Şiddet","Risk"};
    String[] strRıskUserr={spOlasilik.getSelectedItem().toString(),spFrekans.getSelectedItem().toString(),spSiddet.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            (Double.parseDouble(spFrekans.getSelectedItem().toString())*Double.parseDouble(spOlasilik.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    *Double.parseDouble(spSiddet.getSelectedItem().toString()))+""};

    int startLeft=(7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10)+2;

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){


        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        canvas.drawRect(startLeft,28,startLeft+15,43,paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setTextSize(2f);
        canvas.drawText(strRısk[i],startLeft ,31,paint);
        paint.setTextSize(5);
        canvas.drawText(strRıskUserr[i],startLeft+5 ,38,paint);
        paint.setTextSize(3f);




        canvas.drawLine(startLeft,32,startLeft+15,32,paint);

        startLeft+=18;

    }

    canvas.drawText("X",(7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10)+18 ,38,paint);
    canvas.drawText("X",(7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10)+36 ,38,paint);
    canvas.drawText("=",(7*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/10)+54 ,38,paint);
    //paint.settext
    canvas.drawLine(1,44,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,44,paint);
    canvas.drawText("Tehlike Açıklaması",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/6)+5 ,49,paint);
    TextPaint mTextPaint=new TextPaint();
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(3);
    mTextPaint.setLetterSpacing(0.15f);
    StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(edAciklamaTehlike.getText().toString(),
            mTextPaint, (canvas.getWidth()/2)-10, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 3f, 0.0f, false);
    canvas.save();
    startX = 2;
    startY = 56;
    canvas.translate(startX, startY);
    mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();


    canvas.drawText("Fotoğraf",(4*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/6)+15 ,49,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(1,52,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,52,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(3*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/6 ,44,3*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/6,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-50,paint);

    if (bitmap!=null){

        Bitmap scaledbitmap3=getResizedBitmap(bitmap,100,100);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbitmap3,0,0,paint);

    }


    canvas.drawLine(1,(((myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-44)/2)+19,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2,(((myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-44)/2)+19,paint);
    canvas.drawText("Risk Açıklaması",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/6)+5 ,(((myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-44)/2)+24,paint);
    mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(edAciklamaRisk.getText().toString(),
            mTextPaint, (canvas.getWidth()/2)-10, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 3f, 0.0f, false);
    canvas.save();
    startX = 2;
    startY = (((myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-44)/2)+30;
    canvas.translate(startX, startY);
    mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.drawLine(1,(((myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-44)/2)+27,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2,(((myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-44)/2)+27,paint);



    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(8);
    paint.setLetterSpacing(0.1f);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("DÜZELTİCİ ÖNLEYİCİ FALİYET",myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-34,paint);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    canvas.drawRect(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-30,(myPageInfo.getPageWidth())-1,myPageInfo.getPageHeight()-30,paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    canvas.drawRect(5,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-25,12,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-18,paint);
    canvas.drawRect((myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+5,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-25,(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+12,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-18,paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setTextSize(3f);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    //canvas.save();
    //canvas.scale(1f, 1f);
    canvas.drawText("Düzeltici Faaliyet/Meydana gelmiş bir uygunsuzluk için",13,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-20,paint);
    canvas.drawText("Önleyici Faaliyet/Meydana gelebilecek bir uygunsuzluk için",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+13,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-20,paint);
    paint.setTextSize(4);
    if (chDuzeltici.isChecked())
        canvas.drawText("X",6,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-20,paint);
    if (chOnleyici.isChecked())
        canvas.drawText("X",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+6,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-20,paint);


    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-17,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-17,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8,myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8,paint);

    canvas.drawText("Alınması Gereken Önlemler",(6*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+10,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-10,paint);
    mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(edAlinmasiGerekenOnlem.getText().toString(),
            mTextPaint, (17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 3f, 0.0f, false);
    canvas.save();
    startX = 2;
    startY =(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-7;
    canvas.translate(startX, startY);
    mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawLine((17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+4,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8,(17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+4,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawLine((17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+10,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8,(17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+10,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);

    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-8+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawText("Uygunsuzluğun Giderilmesi İçin Yapılan Çalışmalar",5*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)-2+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);

    mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(edUygunsuzlugunGiderilmesi.getText().toString(),
            mTextPaint, (17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 3f, 0.0f, false);
    canvas.save();
    startX = 2;
    startY =(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8)+1;
    canvas.translate(startX, startY);
    mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawLine((17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+4,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),(17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+4,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawLine((17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+10,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),(17*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20)+10,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+1+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);


    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    canvas.drawRect(5,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+6+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),12,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+13+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawRect((myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+5,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+6+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+12,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+13+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawText("Uygunsuzluk Giderildi",13,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+10+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawText("Uygunsuzluk Giderilmedi",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+13,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+10+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    paint.setTextSize(4);
    if (chGiderildi.isChecked())
        canvas.drawText("X",6,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+10+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    else
        canvas.drawText("X",(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/2)+6,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+10+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    paint.setTextSize(3f);

    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+18+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+18+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawText("            Çalışmayı Yapan                                                      İş Güvenliği Uzmanı                " +
                    "                            Kontrol Eden Ve Onaylayan",13,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+25+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    canvas.drawLine(myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/3,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+18+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/3,
            myPageInfo.getPageHeight()-30,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(2*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/3,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+18+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),2*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/3,
            myPageInfo.getPageHeight()-30,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(1,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+30+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),myPageInfo.getPageWidth()-1,
            (myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+30+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
        paint.setTextSize(2f);
    canvas.drawText("             Ad, Soyad, imza                                                                        Ad, Soyad, imza    " +
            "                                                                    Ad, Soyad, imza",20,(myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/2)+35+(2*myPageInfo.getPageHeight()/8),paint);
    paint.setTextSize(5f);
    canvas.drawText("YS-ISG-017",1,myPageInfo.getPageHeight()-4,paint);

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    canvas.drawText("YT-"+date,16*myPageInfo.getPageWidth()/20,myPageInfo.getPageHeight()-4,paint);

    paint.setTextSize(3f);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(-90);
    canvas.drawText("Termin Tarihi",-228,220,paint);
    canvas.drawText("Tamamlama",-284,220,paint);
    canvas.restore();


    document.finishPage(myPage);

    File file=new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Document.pdf");

    try {
        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    document.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PDF OLUŞTURULDU",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2k9i.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Open the file that you want to save as a PDF, and then tap File on your tablet or tap the File icon. on your phone.
On the File menu, tap Print.
If not already selected, tap Microsoft Print to PDF on your tablet or tap PDF on your phone.
Tap Print.
On your tablet, the Save Output As page appears.